# org-capture templates, relative dates

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I'm trying to create an `org-capture` template that contains dates relative to the value of `%t`. I understand that with `C-1` I can prompt for a particular date, and I'm looking for the day prior and the Friday after. I got this far, but now it seems to take today's date, not the particular date selected in the org-capture modal:

```lisp
(org-read-date nil nil "-1" nil (org-time-string-to-time "%t"))
(org-read-date nil nil "+fri" nil (org-time-string-to-time "%t"))
```

I also struggled with the `"+fri"`, which seems to return the Friday *after* the date. I was hoping to have the particular date if that particular date is a Friday.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What you are asking is unclear to me: in a capture template, `%t` is either replaced by the current time (if you call `org-capture`) or it is replaced by whatever time stamp is at point in the current buffer (if you call `org-agenda-capture`). AFAICT, there is no prompting, i.e. you cannot enter a time interactively.

Comment: I guess what you want is `%^t` - however, filling in values interactively is the last step in template expansion, so I don't think you can get the value, manipulate it and insert it back into the template for further expansion. It may be possible through lisp expressions in the template, but the whole thing seems fragile to me. An example of what exactly you are trying to accomplish (i.e. an example of an entry that the capture template is *supposed* to create) would go a long way towards clarifying the question and possibly enabling either a solution or suggestions for another way.

Comment: Thanks. I had understood that `:time-prompt` would allow me to prompt for a datetime other than use the current or the datetime at point. The below answer comes very close to what I was looking for. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but it is what I used to specify a date two days in the future.  It took me quite a while to figure this out (not an elisp expert)

```
; excerpt from capture template

;; technique to set deadline relative to today's date

;;      DEADLINE: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+2\"))
```

Got the idea from one of Sacha Chua's posts.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much. I'd been struggling with this based on SC's post [here](https://sachachua.com/blog/2015/08/org-mode-date-arithmetic/). I tried to build an if statement that would return `t` if `t` is a Friday and `(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t "+fri"))` if not. Is this within the realm of the possible?

Comment: org-read-date is an internal org-mode function, and as such is documented mostly indirectly.  Sorry, this is the limit of my expertise, but you can always try emailing Sacha, she is likely to answer.